# Error HTTP 500- javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate: NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, struts, apache-commons-beanutils

I get this

> javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate: NullPointerException

when I left the page open for a while (about 30 mins) and then clicked on the 'Submit' button on my page. I have seen a couple of posts on Indexing on StackOverflow and Googled and I went through them, trying to understand and implement, but nothing seems to be helping. Here is the error screenshot:

```
HTTP Status 500 - BeanUtils.populate
type Exception report
message BeanUtils.populate
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1254)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:821)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:515)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:428)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:770)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:801)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:881)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:808)
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1252)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:821)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**FORM (PhaseTrackerForm.java):**

```
private PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo[] selectApprList;

public PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo[] getSelectApprList() {
     
    return selectApprList;
}

public void setSelectApprList(PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo[] selectApprList) {
    this.selectApprList = selectApprList;
     
}
```

**FORM (PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo):**

```
private String dbName;
private String schemaName;
private String serviceName;
private String action;
private String phase2MoveDate;
private String approverProfileId;
private ArrayList approverList;




public String getDbName() {
    return dbName;
}

public void setDbName(String dbName) {
    this.dbName = dbName;
}

public ArrayList getApproverList() {
    return approverList;
}

public void setApproverList(ArrayList approverList) {
    this.approverList = approverList;
}
     
public String getApproverProfileId() {
    return approverProfileId;
}

public void setApproverProfileId(String approverProfileId) {
    this.approverProfileId = approverProfileId;
}

public String getSchemaName() {
    return schemaName;
}

 
public void setSchemaName(String schemaName) {
    this.schemaName = schemaName;
}

public String getServiceName() {
    return serviceName;
}

 
public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
}

public String getAction() {
    return action;
}

public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}

public String getPhase2MoveDate() {
    return phase2MoveDate;
}

public void setPhase2MoveDate(String phase2MoveDate) {
    this.phase2MoveDate = phase2MoveDate;
}
```

**JSP Code:**

```
<logic:iterate id="selectApprList" name="phaseTrackerForm"   indexId="i" property="selectApprList" type="com.cisco.rdac.info.PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo">
     
    <bean:define id="myOptions" name="selectApprList" property="approverList" type="java.util.Collection"/>
     
        <tr>
            <td >
                <bean:write name="selectApprList" property="dbName"/>
            </td>
            <td >
                <bean:write name="selectApprList" property="schemaName"/>
            </td>
            <td >
                <bean:write name="selectApprList" property="serviceName"/>
            </td>
            <logic:equal name="moveTo" value="phase2" >
                <td>
                    <bean:write name="selectApprList" property="action"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <logic:empty name="selectApprList" property="phase2MoveDate">
                        N/A
                    </logic:empty>
                    <logic:notEmpty name="selectApprList" property="phase2MoveDate">
                        <bean:write name="selectApprList" property="phase2MoveDate"/>
                    </logic:notEmpty>
                </td>
            </logic:equal>
            <td >
              <html:select indexed="true" name="selectApprList" property="approverProfileId" style="font-size: 90%;">
                <html:options collection="myOptions" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
              </html:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </logic:iterate>
```

**struts-config.xml mapping:**

```
<action
     name="phaseTrackerForm"
     path="/phaseTracker"
     scope="session"
     parameter="methodToCall"
     validate="true"
     input="/WEB-INF/pages/jsp/phaseTrackerInfoPage.jsp"
     type="com.test.actions.PhaseTrackerAction">
     <forward name="phaseTrackerRequest" path="/WEB-INF/pages/jsp/phaseTrackerInfoPage.jsp" />
     <forward name="phaseTrackerSelectAppr" path="/WEB-INF/pages/jsp/phaseTrackerSelApprPage.jsp" />
     <forward name="sameApprover" path="/WEB-INF/pages/jsp/phaseTrackerSelSameApprPage.jsp" />
     <forward name="phaseTrackerSubmit" path="/WEB-INF/pages/jsp/phaseTrackerSubmittedPage.jsp" />
</action>
```

I understood indexing getters and setters but `selectApprList` is the id of `logic:iterate` tag and a `PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo` array. I think this array type is supposed to work but I get the error anyway. I'm using Struts and work on the maintenance of this code so can't do any major changes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that `selectApprList is the id of` logic:iterate`tag, but it matters that it's a name of`` tag. Looking at your code I didn't find getter for this property and/or getters for the objects it contains.

Similar issue you can find:

> The question now is, is the new instance ready to deal with setting
> values on your ArrayList field?  Struts will not instantiate that list
> for you, it wouldn't know how to.  So make sure that when Struts
> accesses your ActionForm, the ArrayList already exists.

You can find an [example](https://mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/) how to use `<logic:iterate>` tag.

Comment: I added the getters and setters for `selectApprList in PhaseTrackerForm` . Also, the getters and setters of the contents inside the array are also there in `PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo`. I have tried putting index in the getter/setter arguments of `selectApprList` but it gives a compilation error because it returns an array type. Do let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I added an initialization for the array in my `PhaseTrackerForm` as `private PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo[] selectApprList=new PhaseTrackerSelectApprInfo[0];` but now instead of `NullPointerException`, I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: everything seems to work fine if I have a session timeout of -1 or submit within the given value. If it exceeds that value (say 30 mins), and then I click on the 'Submit' button, it throws this error.

Comment: The value of ArrayList should be repopulated in the scope of session.